# eclipse can not locate my foregroundcameraplugin.xml file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

so im making this cordova / phonegap application.
I found out that The default Phonegap (Cordova) Camera Plugin calls the native camera and this makes Android Garbage Collector to kill background applications.

so I found a plugin that fixes this :

https://code.google.com/p/foreground-camera-plugin/

now I followed the steps as these guys told. and I'm having the following problems that I cant resolve and need help on.

1. There was a problem with the cameraActivity.java it did not recognize thegenerated file R.java

[image]

then I used an import statement to make it have access to this file 
import statement : import java.android.R;

after this eclipse doesnt recognize the foregroundcameraplugin.xml.

[image]

besides this my my styles.xml files in values-v11 and values-v14 directories are giving an error

"Error retrieving parent for item; no reources found that match the given name @android: Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar  "

[image]

[image]

this is how my forground camera plugin looks like :

[image]

If anyone knows how too fix this please let me know

thank you

Comment: Sometimes `Eclipse` adds `R` file by itself, check your code. If Eclipse imported `R` file, delete it. Clean your project and try to run it.

Comment: if i delete the R file my project wont compile

Comment: I didn't mean to delete file, delete the import statement `import android.R`, clean your project and try to run. R files are automatically generated, your package should have in `/res` folder, you have to use it. `android.R` is a kind of default file. Check this answer : [import android.R in Eclipse : Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15309999/1106598)

Comment: now I get it why my CameraActivity.java file has an error. where do I remove the import android.R statement from ? .... from my Camera.Activity.java file ?

Comment: Yes, it is in your java file on top. it is a `import` command, you will see. Check your all classes. If you are using Eclipse auto import command (Ctrl+Shift+O) this class is usually added by Eclipse.

Comment: okay after I remove the import command how will I generate the R.java file which includes all my up to date resources ? because when I try to run the project it fails to run

Comment: and another thing is that when ever I click the run button my eclipse starts re-indexing repositories .... and the computer fan starts up and the computer speed drops until I stop the re-indexing

Comment: Clean your project (Project->Clean) and try to build again. If it fails to build and doesn't generate R file, check your XML files. Might be error in your xml files.

Comment: when I try to clean the project it gives me the following error :

[2013-06-18 17:27:18 - cordova_camTestApp] Failed to create BuildConfig class

Comment: in your `AndroidManifest` file, what is target SDK and minSDK?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reply the error with the new **Eclipse Kepler** and found the solution: upgrade your **ADT to version 22 and install Android SDK Build-tools** by SDK manager. I have also commited a new classpath file for ForegroundCameraPlugin project with some changes (included Android Private Libraries). Thanks to your contact and the help of this link: [Eclipse giving error, missing R.java file after recent update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update?answertab=active#tab-top)