# Error accessing xml file in android

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and recently developed a weird error in my code.
I was following a tutorial that directed the coder to go to project>clean (in eclipse).  After I clicked it my code developed errors whenever I tried to access a resource.  I received an error on the R.  It said that the variable R cannot be recognized.  Eclipse recommends that I import the package "R" which did not work.  An example of the line of code that had the error on is:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

After I imported "R" eclipse was unable to recognize/find `activity_main`.

Comment: That means one of two things-  either you have a compilation error in your resources, or you need to do a clean build in Eclipse.

Comment: Go through this link

[import android.R in Eclipse : Why?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309941/import-android-r-in-eclipse-why

Comment: I think there is problem in your project resource part it may xml,drawable or string due to this problem your R class not generated try to find it and resolved after your R class automatically generated.

Comment: Check the console pane in eclipse. It sometimes has more information about errors in the XML resource files.

Answer (score 1):

You can check some steps. 
 
1. resource activity_main layout or others resource ok or not.
2. your activity in above delete import Android.R 
3. add your package_name.R for example. if your package name is com.example.helloworld, then import com.example.helloworld.R 
4.delete bin folder and gen folder of your project. 
5. clean your project , project=>clean. 
and 6. finally restart your eclipse.

When any resource mismatch then this type error show.

Best of luck

Comment: Your step 3 is only necessary if there is more than one package. If there is only one package then you never need to import your own R.java class.